# Make Gmail auto-delete old emails from phone

Tags: gmail

My mom's phone has stopped receiving mail because apparently, there isn't enough free space.

Is it possible to configure the Gmail app to auto-delete mail older that a month from the phone but not from the server?

Comment: Is the device rooted? Also, this seems related to XY problem.

Comment: @Firelord it's NOT rooted. What XY problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by setting the "Days of mail to sync" in the gmail app's setting. This setting is configurable per account.

Source: [Choose how many days of mail to sync](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/2819491?hl=en)

Comment: "Days of mail to sync" only available for Gmail accounts and not for (for example) Outlook accounts