# Gmail app high storage usage

Tags: custom-roms, android-10, moto-x4, pixel-experience

I have installed custom rom on my android device 10 days ago. The rom was official pixel experience from xda for moto x4(payton). Today, I have noticed that Gmail android app have used about 1.2gb as user data and a total of 1.3gb. What may be the reason? Now, I have cleared storage. How to solve if it occurs again.

Device: Motorola Moto x4

ROM:pixel experience official Android 10

Root status: unrooted

Comment: Related question: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/138990/how-can-i-make-the-gmail-app-consume-less-space Additionally you can disable the setting __Automatic attachment download via Wifi__

Comment: One fundamental reason is that any mail addressed to you has two copies - one in important and one in All mail. If you receive 20 Mb attachment, it eats up 40 Mb space

Comment: @Robert Now, I have unchecked Automatic attachment download via WIFI. I'll update if it occurs again.